# Url query Reach Route - React

Tags: node.js, react, url, route, react-router

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma API em node.js que me retorna id e nome de produtos e de supermercados
Quando faço um get em /supermercados passando via url params `/:idSupermercado` eu consigo pegar esse parâmetro no componente por `this.props.idSupermercado.` 
Até ai ok.

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para pegar uma url query.

Ex: o link no final ficaria assim localhost:3000/search/idSupermercado/?produto=batata

Como faço para pegar esse ?produto=batata no component?

Estou usando [reach router](https://reach.tech/router) para trabalhar com as rotas

Answer (score 1):

No caso, para pegar os queryParams, você pode acessar `this.props.location.search`.

Virá no formato `?produto=batata`, aí só formatar. Inclusive, pode usar outras libs pra fazer a conversão pa